# Jest: how to mock a function which is used by another function of the same module

Tags: jestjs

I am trying to test a function which depends on another function in the same module. I would like to mock the second one and the approach that I have tried is the following:

`utils.js`:

```js
const buildEngine = () => 'Engine';

const buildCar = () => {
  const engine = buildEngine();
  return engine + ' and ' + 'Car Body';
};

module.exports = {
  buildEngine,
  buildCar
};
```

`utils.spec.js`:

```js
function mockModule() {
  const original = require.requireActual('./utils');
  return { ...original, buildEngine: jest.fn(() => 'Mock Engine') };
}

it('Builds a Car', () => {
  jest.mock('./utils', () => mockModule());

  const utils = require.requireMock('./utils');

  expect(utils.buildEngine()).toBe('Mock Engine');
  expect(utils.buildCar()).toBe('Mock Engine and Car Body');
});
```

What happens is that even if I am able to mock the "buildEngine" function, when I test the "buildCar" function this continues to reference the unmocked "buildEngine".
Please help.

Comment: What's your motivation? Normally, mocking a function would mean you don't care about the original implementation (which is either kept or replaced).

Comment: I want to test "buildCar" independently from "buildEngine" and hence I need to mock "buildEngine".

Comment: I understand the issue but find the approach invalid. You're trying to affect the internal of `buildCar()` instead of maintaining an implementation-agnostic approach. If `buildCar()` should allow building cars with different engines, the implementation should reflect that (i.e. have argument). Otherwise, you're testing something that is not testable.

Comment: The most interesting scenario is different cars using the same engine.

Comment: But since `buildCar()` doesn't have any argument, the expected result is always the same. Why would you mock an internally used function, when this is not even a real-life scenario?

Comment: It's just the simplest example it came up to my mind.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution:

`utils.js`:

```js
const buildEngine = () => 'Engine';

const buildCar = () => {
  const engine = exports.buildEngine();
  return engine + ' and ' + 'Car Body';
};

exports.buildEngine = buildEngine;
exports.buildCar = buildCar;
```

`utils.spec.js`:

```js
const utils = require('./utils');

describe('utils', () => {
  it('Builds a Car', () => {
    const buildEngineSpy = jest.spyOn(utils, 'buildEngine').mockReturnValue('Mock Engine');
    expect(utils.buildCar()).toBe('Mock Engine and Car Body');
    expect(buildEngineSpy).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    buildEngineSpy.mockRestore();
  });

  it('build engine original implementation', () => {
    expect(utils.buildEngine()).toBe('Engine');
    expect(utils.buildCar()).toBe('Engine and Car Body');
  });
});
```

Unit test result:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/46437290/utils.spec.js
  utils
    ✓ Builds a Car (4ms)
    ✓ build engine original implementation (1ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.908s, estimated 2s
```

Here is the completed demo: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/46437290

Comment: This works, thank you!  Just to note, this works because in `utils.js` the call is being made to `exports.buildEngine()`.